# Java: can't display the image in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am learning to make gui in JAVA, and I am trying to add an image in my JFrame, this is the code I tried:

```
    public class MyApp extends JFrame {

    private ImageIcon img;
    private JLabel imglabel;

    public MyApp(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("img.jpg"));
        //adding the label for the above Icon
        imglabel = new JLabel("this is the image");
        add(imglabel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApp app = new MyApp();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.pack();
        app.setVisible(true);
        app.setTitle("reminder");
    }
}
```

but I cannot see any image being displayed on the screen! where did I go wrong?

also the image and the class is in the same directory:

[image]

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is the image in the same directory as your class? If it's a jar, is the image included in the jar?

Comment: yes, it is in the same directory. see the edit

Answer (score 2):

The icon is never set!

```
imglabel = new JLabel("this is the image");
```

Should be..

```
imglabel = new JLabel("this is the image");
imgLabel.setIcon(img); // or use the 3 arg constructor for JLabel
```

Comment: it should be "imglabel" I guess, and sorry but it isn't working mate!

Comment: OK.. instead of using an image icon to load the image, use `ImageIO.read(URL)` - it will provide helpful information if it cannot find or load the image.

Comment: changed : `imglabel.new JLabel("this is the img")` to `imglabel = new JLabel(img)` and it worked! Thanks for the help

Comment: your suggestion was not working for me at this point, so I am updating what worked here, accept it and I will then accept the answer :)

Comment: I rejected the edit. If you think that's the best answer (I disagree), please post it as an answer (which you can then accept, after some time).